# Why is my SQLAlchemy Update query not updating?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've built the following code to get some records, iterate through them and do some stuff and then update the database with the result of the "stuff":

```
matches = session.query(
    MatchesOP.match_id,
    MatchesOP.match_url,
    MatchesOP.p1_odds,
    MatchesOP.p2_odds,
    ).filter(MatchesOP.p1_odds == None, MatchesOP.p2_odds == None).limit(10)
for match in matches:
    # Do some stuff and return two floats - in this example hardcoded returns of 1.5 and 2.0 to test
    update_match = session.query(
        MatchesOP.match_id,
        MatchesOP.p1_odds,
        MatchesOP.p2_odds,
        ).filter(MatchesOP.match_id == match[0])
    update_match.update({MatchesOP.p1_odds: 1.5})
    update_match.update({MatchesOP.p2_odds: 2.0})
```

However, the `update()` statements aren't updating the database. I've looked at both the queries and they seem to run fine. Am I misunderstanding how to use the `update` method?

Comment: Do you commit at any point?

Comment: Does `update_match.all()` return anything?

Comment: @IljaEverilä - I don't no. The book I'm following says this method 'causes records to be updated outside of the session'

Comment: @RubenHelsloot - yep. Returns all the many thousands of records :)

Comment: @IljaEverilä - ```session.commit()``` works. Happy to accept that as the answer. Getting rather annoyed with this book now as that's twice it's been wrong...